# Java instead of XTend in XText project

Tags: java, xtext

According to the book about XText and XTend:
"You can still generate Java stub classes by customizing the MWE2 workflow".

What do i change in my MWE2 file to make this happen?

Currently GenerateMyDsl.mwe2 looks like this: http://pastebin.com/3jp4B1X7

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify it on a per fragment level, or once in the config like this:

```
   // in MWE file
   component = XtextGenerator {
        configuration = {
            ...
            code = {
                preferXtendStubs = false
            }
        }
        ...
```